# CodeIgniter and IIS

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my PHP/CodeIgniter application set up and running locally on IIS, but I'm having problems with the URLs:

http://localhost/index.php/Main/Action <- doesn't work ("No input file specified)

http://localhost/index.php?Main/Action <- works

Any ideas on how I can get the first url to work?

Comment: Shouldn't it be http://localhost/Main/Action? (I'm not super familiar with CodeIgniter, but other frameworks usually drop the `index.php` part like F3)

Comment: Sounds like a problem with URL rewriting. Are you using an example web.config file supplied with the framework? Is IIS configured to allow local web.config files?